# Использование событии в приложении

Tags: c#, события

Добрый день, прошу совета с грамотным использованием событии в приложениях.
У меня был проект клиент-сервер на сокетах.
Вроде бы разобравшись в делегатах и событиях решил уйти от Console.WriteLine(), там где вывод информации. Для вывода использую события.
Вот код самого класса с сервером:

```
public delegate void GetMessage(string message);
public class Server
{
    private Socket listenSocket;
    private IPEndPoint ip;

    public event GetMessage ServerStarted;
    public event GetMessage ClientConnected;
    public event GetMessage ClientWrited;
    public event GetMessage ClientDisconected;

    public Server(int port)
    {
        listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
    }

    public void StartServer (int backlog)
    {
        listenSocket.Bind(ip);
        listenSocket.Listen(backlog);
        ServerStarted?.Invoke($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString()}] Сервер запущен. Ожидаю подключения..");
    }


    public void ClientAccept ()
    {
        Socket clientSocket = listenSocket.Accept();
        ClientConnected?.Invoke($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString()}] [{((IPEndPoint)clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString()}] подключился");
        Thread cl = new Thread(() => MessageDecode(clientSocket));
        cl.Start();
    }


    private void MessageDecode (Socket clientSocket)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[clientSocket.SendBufferSize];
        int readByte;
        commands = cl.CreateCommands();
        do
        {
            readByte = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);
            byte[] rData = new byte[readByte];
            Array.Copy(buffer, rData, readByte);
            string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rData);

            ClientWrited?.Invoke($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString()}] [{((IPEndPoint)clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString()}] написал: " + data);
            clientSocket.Send(new byte[3] {89,69,83 });
        } while (readByte > 0);

        ClientDisconected?.Invoke($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString()}] Клиент отключился");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Вот как я вызываю все в Program.cs:

```
 class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int port = 904;

        Server srv = new Server(port);

        srv.ServerStarted += Srv_ServerStarted;
        srv.ClientConnected += Srv_ClientConnected;
        srv.ClientWrited += Srv_ClientWrited;
        srv.ClientDisconected += Srv_ClientDisconected;

        try
        {
            srv.StartServer(500);

        }catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString()} Не удается запустить сервер!!!!!!]");
        }

       while (true)
        {
            srv.ClientAccept();
        } 
    }

    private static void Srv_ClientDisconected(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    private static void Srv_ClientWrited(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    private static void Srv_ClientConnected(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    private static void Srv_ServerStarted(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Собственно правильно ли все я сделал?

Comment: Зачем 100500 событий вместо одного - если в итоге все равно они обрабатываются одинаково? На будущее? Зачем? "Тебе это не понадобится" (гугли YAGNI). Какую проблему вы этим решили? Мне видится, что по большей части вы породили кучу потенциальных проблем, вместо этого.

Comment: Вот этот момент интересен, получается события новое  надо создавать, только в том случае, если оно иначе будет, что то делать?
Мне получается достаточно одного события, и просто его вызывать там где надо?

Comment: Ну, по ситуации надо смотреть - если это библиотека для использования другими людьми и есть предпосылки что эти события нужны будут  - да, куча событий имеет смысл существовать - но опять же, без фанатизма. В вашем же случае необходимости в таком зоопарке нет, во всяком случае пока.

Comment: чем то напоминает WinForms, там тоже, чтобы что-то на экран вывести, надо Invoke делать. А тут зачем? у Вас что вывод в лог однопотоковый? Возьмите библиотеку, которая будет синхронизировать вывод в лог сама и не мучайтесь

Comment: Тут скорее попытка понимания как пользоваться событиями на практике:)